# Location of various javax.xml.* packages within the Java 6 SDK

Tags: java, xml, soap, namespaces, libraries

Alright, so recently I was using Notepad++ for all of my programming needs, but I've started using Eclipse for larger-scale Java projects now.  I decided to pick up an old project of mine which used various classes within the "javax.xml.*" namespaces.  When I was compiling and running the program with Notepad++ it worked just fine, however Eclipse can't seem to find these packages.

My question is this, since I obviously have the classes somewhere within my current installation of JDK 6 (since I had no problems when using Notepad++), where can I find the location of the .JAR file(s) that include these namespaces/classes so that I can add them to my Eclipse project?

Thanks for any help you can give me!

Regards,
celestialorb

Also, if you're curious about the specific packages I'm looking for they are:

```
javax.xml.soap.*
javax.xml.transform.*
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks!  The rt.jar file worked for me.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your Eclipse perhaps configured to use Java 1.4 libraries for that project? Those packages weren't added to Java SE until 1.5.

Look at Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs to see which versions your Eclipse installation has available (and to add new ones). You can set a default, and also choose for each project which version to use (in the project properties->Build Path->Libraries)